# How to normalize data from a csv file within a specific range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv file as follows:

1,1.23,1.53,1.22,0.96,0.24,1.22,1.22,2.12,0.76,0.99
2,1.17,1.52,0.67,0.93,0.14,1.60,1.23,2.22,0.55,0.65
3,2.21,1.52,0.66,0.33,0.15,1.72,1.18,1.45,0.98,0.33

I want to read all the data in the csv file EXCEPT the first value in each row.

I then want to normalise the data to a specific range.

Thanks to stackoverflow, I have learnt to read the relevant data, and have managed to research enough Python to normalize the data.

This data (if my code is correct) normalizes the data to a range of 0 to 1.

I cannot however work out how to normalise the data to a different range (for example 0.001 to 1).

```
import numpy

array = numpy.genfromtxt('Anaconda3JamesData/james_test_3.csv', delimiter=',')

# get minimum and maximum values of 
# all data except the first value in each row
maximum=array[:, 1:].max()
minimum=array[:, 1:].min()   

print (minimum)
print (maximum)

# display the contents of the csv file except the first value in each row
print (array[:,1:])

# normalise all data in the array except 
# the first value of each row
x = (array[:,1:] - minimum)/(maximum - minimum)

print (x)
```

My output is:

0.14
2.22
[[1.23 1.53 1.22 0.96 0.24 1.22 1.22 2.12 0.76 0.99]
 [1.17 1.52 0.67 0.93 0.14 1.6  1.23 2.22 0.55 0.65]
 [2.21 1.52 0.66 0.33 0.15 1.72 1.18 1.45 0.98 0.33]]
[[0.52403846 0.66826923 0.51923077 0.39423077 0.04807692 0.51923077
  0.51923077 0.95192308 0.29807692 0.40865385]
 [0.49519231 0.66346154 0.25480769 0.37980769 0.         0.70192308
  0.52403846 1.         0.19711538 0.24519231]
 [0.99519231 0.66346154 0.25       0.09134615 0.00480769 0.75961538
  0.5        0.62980769 0.40384615 0.09134615]]

This does indeed look like my normalization code is correct. It's normalizing the required data in-between 0 and 1. But how would I normalize the data in-between 0.001 and 1? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to scale your normalized range and introduce and intercept to avoid 0 normalized values. Here's how I'd do it.

Your present transformation is equivalent to the equation below:

```
(x - min)/(max - min) = n/1
```

To scale it to a range of size 0.999, here's the required transformation:

```
(x - min)/(max - min) = n/0.999
((x - min)/(max - min)) * 0.999 = n
```

However, this would leave you with a normalized range of [0,0.999]. Therefore, you need to introduce an intercept of 0.001 to give you a normalized range of [0.001,1]

```
0.001 + ((x - min)/(max - min)) * 0.999 = n
```

Applying it to your script would then give:

```
x = 0.001 + ((array[:,1:] - min)/(max - min)) * 0.999
```

Comment: I received an 'unsupported operand' error but was corrected by using

x = 0.001 + ((array[:,1:] - minimum)/(maximum - minimum)) * 0.999

in my code. Works perfectly now.

Comment: @James Forgive me if my eyes are failing but I do not see any differences between the two!